# Syntax to put a variable in a string in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

A question I think pretty simple but I never had to do it in swift. it's pretty simple PHP but here I do not find my solution on the internet.

ask: I would like to add a variable in this chain of character. Instead of 123, I would need a variable.

```
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_123.json"

result = final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_VARAIBLE.json"
```

Can you give me the syntax in swift3 or direct me to a good tutorial.

Comment: `final let` is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a string using string formatting.

```
String(format:"https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_%d.json", variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift4 You can add a string in these ways:

```
var myString = "123" // Or VARAIBLE Here any string you pass!! 
var urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_\(myString).json"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let variable = 123
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_\(variable).json"
```

**\(variable)** is what you need

**OR**

use string formatting

```
let variable = 123
final let urlString = String(format:"https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_%d.json", variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is good documentation about Strings in [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285). Your options are:

Concatenating Strings

```
let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_" + value + ".json"
```

String interpolation

```
let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_\(value).json"
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing it could be:

```
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_" + variablename + ".json"
```

You can also do it like this (a little more typesafe):

```
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_\(variablename).json"
```

Swift will read `\(variablename)` into the string automatically and accepts - among all things - integers.

Answer (score -1):

```
let variable = 123
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_" + variable + ".json"
```

or

```
final let urlString = "https://ozsqiqjf.preview.infomaniak.website/empdata_\(variable).json"
```